# redirect google users from indexed html snapshot to my site main page

Tags: seo

i have business listing site (www.brate.com) where people can search for local businesses and rate them.
the entire site is build using GWT (i.e. Ajax) and the all content is generated dynamically. Now i am in a phase where i want the site to be SEO friendly, below is my approach and please advise me if its the best way to implement it.

1- create static HTML snapshot of each business and its related data (site, address, phone number, user reviews...etc) and put all the generated HTML files under a single directory
2- create a sitemap xml file that contains all the above HTML links
3- configure webmaster to crawl and index all generated HTML snapshots

now my logic is that when google search query list one of the above generated html files in its search results i want to redirect the user to the site main page (www.brate.com) not the html snapshot.
can i use a redirect like "" in the generated snapshots?
if not what is the best way to achieve the above mentioned logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sameeh, one suggested approach for GWT

1. Ensure that you have correctly handled history tokens for all your pages in GWT. Let the tokens start with exclamation (!).
2. Associate GWT history tokens with generated pages using #! notation
3. Let tokens be keyword rich as we do for any [URL optimization in SEO](http://www.searchenabler.com/blog/url-optimization-tips-for-seo/)

Read through https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ for understanding #! notation.

Details on support by Bing: http://searchengineland.com/bing-now-supports-googles-crawlable-ajax-standard-84149

Comment: thanks for the reply khadim, i already researched google's webmaster docs. but as you know GWT application responds to url requests with an optimized version of the application according to client's browser. when using htmlunit to generate html snapshots i have the choice to return one snapshot for one browser which can cause cross-browser javascript error. my question is that can i use url redirects in my html snapshot to redirect the user to my homepage and make gwt take care of responding with the right build as per client browser? the html snapshot will be only static html without js

Comment: Sameeh, Assuming that you are going to develop as per specification mentioned above (supporting ?_escaped_fragment_ for giving html pages). In your application make sure only to use #! urls, never ?_escaped_fragment_. No need of any redirection for HTML snapshot as only viewer for it is search engine. 
You can see the sample gwt page "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gwt-bootstrap" 
& its search engine crawlable page "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gwt-bootstrap

Comment: thanks for the support. i managed to index my site just as stated by khadim. i have a question though, when google displays the preview of the page (the one on the right in the search result) does google uses the generated snapshots or calls the site pretty url (the one with #!)?